# Is there an error in this metric space question?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, fractals

> For $\epsilon > 0$ show that there exists $n_{0}$ so that $d_{H}(E_{n},E_{m}) < \epsilon$ for $n, m \geq n_{0}$ where $E_{n}$ is the graph $$E_{n} = \{(t,t^{n}) \; \colon \; t \in [0,1]\}.$$ 
>   Hint: Perhaps it is easier to spot a set $E$ with $d_{H}(E_{n},E) < \epsilon$ for large $n$ and use the triangle inequality

My question is should the interval in the definition of $E_{n}$ be $[0,1)$ instead? An obvious candidate for $E$ from the hint is the set $E = \{(t,0)\; \colon \; t \in [0,1)\}$ if this were the case. The question doesn't specify, but I believe we are working with $t \in \mathbb{R}$ as well. Since we can always find $n$-th roots in the real numbers, isn't the set $E_{n}$ as it's defined above the same for all $n$? Some clarification would be great, or perhaps I'm completely wrong and you can point me in the right direction.

The metric stated is the Hausdorff metric.

Comment: I don't think the set $E$ needs to be the graph of a function.

Comment: If the problem is $t=1$, why not let this value of $t$ be treated separately in the definition of $E$?

Comment: Would it suffice then to set $E = \{(t,0) \; \colon t \in [0,1)\} \cup \{(1,1)\}$?

Comment: Looks good! Now write it out. :)

Comment: @Lightful I don't think that set will work. I believe that $E$ must be compact. I reiterate - consider a set that is not the graph of a function.

Comment: $E$ is not compact because $[0,1)$ is open. That said, I don't know why Mark McClure wants compacity. If you wanted it to be compact anyway you could include $(0,1)$ in $E$.

Comment: Yeah I just realised a few seconds before you posted that so I deleted the comment. Could you explain why $E$ must be compact Mark? Also, isn't the set $E$ that I've defined the set of limit points of the sequence $E_{n}$? Also, nothing immediately springs to mind if we're looking for a set that isn't the graph of a function.

Comment: @Lightful The Hausdorff metric is defined on the set of non-empty compact sets. $E$ *must* be compact.

Comment: There appears to be some conflict with the notes I'm using which is adding to my confusion. It says that, in the case the two sets are compact, we can change the inf in the distance calculation to min instead as merely a special case. This implies that the Hausdorff distance is still defined regardless of whether or not the two sets in question are compact.

Comment: @Lightful Yes, you can define the Hausdorff distance between arbitrary, non-empty sets. It only becomes a metric if you restrict to the non-empty compact sets. For example, the distance between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ is zero. If you want to use the triangle inequality, you'll need the Hausdorff metric - not just the Hausdorff distance.

Comment: Good point about the triangle inequality, that clears things up tremendously. Back to the question then, how about the set $E = \{(0,0)\} \cup \{(1,1)\}$? This is compact, since a metric space is Hausdorff and hence all singletons are closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is stated correctly and that the hint is good. The set $E$ does *not* need to be the graph of a function but it does need to be compact in order to apply the Haudorff metric. Indeed, I think a major point behind the problem is to help you distinguish between closeness in the Hausdorff metric and closeness in the supremum norm, which is really just defined between functions.

For the set $E$, I would choose
$$E = \{(s,0): 0\leq s \leq 1\} \cup \{(1,t): 0 \leq t \leq 1\}.$$
This is the union of a horizontal line segment with a vertical line segment, as shown in the image below. The image also shows the graph of the function $f(x)=x^{80}$.

[image]

As we see, every point on the graph is close to some point in the set $E$ and vice-versa. Intuitively, this is what we mean for two sets to be close in the Hausdorff metric and I think it's fairly straighforward to formalize a proof from here.

Comment: Should the second union not be $\{(1,t) \colon 0 \leq t \leq 1\}$?

Comment: @Lightful Yes. :)